# Get results from past year if 1st of january

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a scheduled job that runs daily ( in the morning or evening, or the next day in the morning) that sends some reports to an FTP.

I want to include in the report only records from the current year.
And if it is 1st of january of the next year, in the morning, I want to show all the records from the past year.
If it is 1st of january in the evening, and I have records from the new year, I want to include only those records from the new year

Example:

```
transfer date    | job run date     | Records with year  
-----------------|------------------|------------------
30.12.2018 08:00 | 30.12.2018 19:00 | 2018  
30.12.2018 08:00 | 31.12.2018 02:00 | 2018  
31:12.2018 08:00 | 31.12.2018 19:00 | 2018  
31.12.2018 08:00 | 01.01.2019 01:00 | 2018  
01.01.2019 08:00 | 01.01.2019 19:00 | 2019  
01.01.2019 08:00 | 02.01.2019 01:00 | 2019
```

In the last column is the record's year that i want

I would like a simple solution, so that the original query is not transformed into a function or stored procedure etc.

What have I tried:

```
SELECT
       DateReceived ,
       UniqueNumber ,
       TransferDate ,
       CompanyCode
FROM
       ExportData
where
       YEAR(convert(datetime,TransferDate)) =
       case
              when year(convert(datetime,Transferdate))=year(getdate())
                     and month(getdate())              =1
                     and day(getdate())                =1
                     then year(getdate())
              when Year(convert(datetime,transferdate))=year(getdate())-1
                     then year(getdate())-1
       end
order by
       TransferDate DESC
```

Comment: What issue you are facing actually?

Comment: It does not return the correct result. In my example query, I get records from 2019 and from 2018

Comment: The trick is, first write the part of the query which establishes the correct year according to your logic - there are two special cases, the morning of 01-Jan where the relevant year is the previous year, the afternoon of 01-Jan where the relevant year is the current year if data exists or else the previous year, and in all other cases the relevant year is the current one. Once you have that, it's just a case of joining to the data on YEAR(TransferDate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this simple adjustment in WHERE condition works for you or not. This will only return records for the Maximum YEAR available in the table.

```
SELECT
   DateReceived ,
   UniqueNumber ,
   TransferDate ,
   CompanyCode
FROM
   ExportData
WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, TransferDate)) =
(
    SELECT YEAR(MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, TransferDate)))
    FROM TransferDate
)
ORDER BY TransferDate DESC;
```

Comment: I think that instead of the last 'TransferDate' it should be 'ExportData'?
This works... It was so simple. 
now, I was just thinking at performance, in case of a large populated table...

Comment: Use of date (transfer or export) depends on your requirement. There will no performance issue for the WHERE condition.

Comment: I thought that because of an extra subquery

Comment: That sub query will execute just once.